# Weighted percentile calculation from group of percentiles

Tags: statistics, computer-science, percentile

Can we calculate the overall k*th* percentile if we have k*th* percentile over 1 minute window for the same time period?

The underlying data is not available. Only the k*th* percentile and count of underlying data is available.

Are there any existing algorithms available for this?
How approximate will the calculated k*th* percentile be?

Comment: It’s not clear exactly what you are asking here.  Specifically, what time periods and data you have and what data you are trying to calculate.  Do you have every percentile and count for every minute?  And are you trying to get the Kth percentile for a longer timespan that includes those minutes?  If so, then yes, it can be approximated with reasonable accuracy.

Comment: I have kth percentile and count for every minute for say a whole day. Can kth percentile for an entire day be calculated based on above 2 inputs. How and what will be accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you have only one percentile (and count) for every time period, then you cannot reasonably estimate that same percentile for the entire time period.

This is because percentiles are only semi-numerical measures (like Means) and don't implicitly tell you enough about their distributions above and below their measured values at each measurement time.  There are a couple of exceptions to the above.

1. If the percentile that you have is the 50th percentile (i.e., the Mean), then you can do some extrapolation to the Mean of the whole time, but it's a bit sketchy and I'm not sure how bad the variance would be.
2. If *all* of your percentile measure are very close together (compared to the actual range of the measured population), then obviously you can use that as a reasonable estimate of the overall percentile.
3. If you can assume with high assurance that every minute's data is an *independent* sampling *of the exact same* population distribution (i.e., there is no time-dependence), then you may be able to combine them, possibly even if the exact distribution is not fully known (has parameter that are unknown, but still known to be fixed over the time-period).  Again I am not sure what the valid functions and variance calculations are for this.
4. If the distribution is known (or can be assumed) to be a specific function or shape with some unknown value or values and where time-dependence has a known role in that function, then you should be able to using weighting and time-adjustments to transform into the same situation as #3 above.  So for instance if the distributions were a time-varying exponential distribution of the form `pdf(k,t) = (k*t)e^-(k*t)` then I believe that you could derive an overall percentile estimate by estimating the value of `k` for by adjust it for each different minute (`t`).

Unfortunately I am not a professional statistician.  I have Math/CS background, enough to have some idea of what's mathematically possible/reasonable, but not enough to tell exactly how to do it.  If you think that your situation falls into one of the above categories, then you might be able to take it to https://stats.stackexchange.com but you will need to also provide the information I mentioned in those categories and/or detailed and specific information about what you are measuring and how you are measuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on statistical instincts  ,The error rate will be  proportional to Standard Deviation of the total set.  If you are creating a approximation  for a longer time span , that includes the discrete chunks of kth percentile . [ clarification may be need for proving this theory.]